# Богатство и богачество различаются только стилистически?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, стилистика, синонимы

> Небо нежное, жемчужное. С него падают редкие капли. Они питают траву
>   на соседней черепичной крыше и сотни выставленных по такому случаю
>   цветочных горшков. Впервые увидела соседку – в шесть утра, ещё
>   неприбранная, она выносила свои **цветущие богачества** на свет,
>   подставляя их листья дождю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что пишет А. М. Камчатнов:
[бога́чество](http://www.drevoslov.ru/bogtree/3960-bogachestvo), -а, сущ., ср. р. От основы *богач/ъ*. Первоначально с собирательным значением (ср. *человечество, купечество, студенчество*), затем со значением отвлеченного качества и, метонимически, предмета, обладающего этим качеством; в этом значении по сравнению с *богатство* (см.) сущ. *богачество* обладает просторечной стилистической окраской.

«**Богачество**, с. *То же, что* **богатство** (*в знач.* 2). Государь земли той съ своими людьми самъ себя, и честь, и богачество, и славу свою, и землю свою, и люди потеряетъ и безоруженъ обрящется» (СлРЯ XI-XVII вв. 1, 259).

Думается мне, что в этом контексте нечасто употребляемое слово *богачество* — именно то, что надо. Оно легко и непринужденно "вписывается" в утренний пейзаж ("глобальной" просторечности я не ощущаю).

*Хочешь знать моё богачество?

Скакуну на свете — скачется,

Мёртвым — спится, птицам — свищется.*

*Юным — рыщется да ищется,

Неразумным бабам — плачется.

— Слёзный дар — моё богачество!*
М. Цветаева (1918)